# VBA: code runs but no output is generated

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook with two sheets, named "Dashboard Supplier View' and "ComputingSolutions". In the dashboard supplier view tab, the user has to write down a value in the named cell "categoryName". When the user writes down "Computing Solutions" in this named cell and runs the code, I want the code to go to the ComputingSolutions sheet and to store all the suppliernames in column A in that sheet into an array, to then print out all suppliernames in the original sheet Dashboard Supplier View.

The "n" variable refers to a named cell on the ComputingSolutions sheet and is the number of suppliers on that sheet. (This number is written down already, the user does not need to change this)

When I run the code, nothing shows up. Nothing is printed on the dashboard supplier view sheet at the designated location. I get no error either. I checked all names and everything is spelled correctly. I'm not sure what could be the issue, but I suspect it has something to do with the activation of the worksheets.

```
Public Sub DashboardSupplier()

Dim category As String
Dim supplierArray() As String
Dim c As Integer

Worksheets("Dashboard Supplier View").Activate

category = Names("categoryName").Value

'Suppliers for selectec category

If category = "Computing Solutions" Then

Worksheets("ComputingSolutions").Activate

n = Names("supplierAmount").Value

ReDim supplierArray(1 To n) As String

    For c = 1 To n

    supplierArray(c) = Cells(3 + c, 1)

    Next c

Worksheets("Dashboard Supplier View").Activate

    For c = 1 To n

    Cells(6 + c, 4) = supplierArray(c)

    Next c

   End If

   End Sub
```

Comment: how does the `n` variable relate to a named cell? Is the cell named `n`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  Put a break (eg) inside the  `If category = "Computing Solutions" Then` block - does your code reach that point?

Comment: n refers to the named call supplierAmount via n = Names("supplierAmount").Value

Comment: Yep, sorry, I just read that, my bad.

Comment: So, the question I actually wanted to ask is the named range `categoryName` on the `Dashboard Supplier View` worksheet, and is `supplierAmount` on `ComputingSolutions`?

Comment: @Tim Williams When I put a breakpoint in the "if statement" block, it simply runs to that breakpoint, but I get no message or anything (note I'm new at VBA and debugging so I may be doing it wrong)

Comment: @AndrewWynn correct

Comment: Where did you put your code?  In a code module or in a sheet code module?

Comment: In VBA, you can press F9 on a line to insert a breakpoint, Press F8 to run the current line of code ONLY, and press F5 to continue execution. You can repeatedly press F8 to "Step through" your code.

Comment: @simpLEMAn I clicked "insert module" then "insert procedure", chose subform. Not sure where I can see where its a code module or sheet code module

Comment: Try changing `supplierArray(c) = Cells(3 + c, 1)` to `supplierArray(c) = ActiveSheet.Cells(3 + c, 1)` and `Cells(6 + c, 4) = supplierArray(c)` to `ActiveSheet.Cells(6 + c, 4) = supplierArray(c)`

Comment: @AndrewWynn went through entire code with F8 - cant seem to find the issue

Comment: @simpLEMAn thanks I tried, but still no output

Comment: @Jolien.A is the code entering the IF statement, or skipping it?

Comment: @AndrewWynn skips it - but thats odd. Why would the if statement not read the value correct? I wrote down Computing Solutions in the named cell on the correct sheet.

Comment: Change all your `Names` by `Range`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I have a solution to this because it was bothering me. I set up your environment as a test, and found that for some reason, `Names("categoryName").Value` was returning the cell address, i.e. it was returning `Names("categoryName").RefersTo`. Try swapping the `.value` part for `.RefersToRange.Value` and see if you have better luck. Here is my working formatted code:

```
Public Sub DashboardSupplier()
    Dim category As String
    Dim supplierArray() As String
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim n As Long
    Worksheets("Dashboard Supplier View").Activate
    category = Range("categoryName").Value
    'Suppliers for selectec category
    If category = "Computing Solutions" Then
        Worksheets("ComputingSolutions").Activate
        n = CLng(Range("supplierAmount").Text)
        ReDim supplierArray(1 To n) As String
        For c = 1 To n
            supplierArray(c) = Cells(3 + c, 1)
        Next c
        Worksheets("Dashboard Supplier View").Activate
        For c = 1 To n
            Cells(6 + c, 4) = supplierArray(c)
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I have no explanation for this behavior.

Comment: This gives me Run-Time error 1004:Application-defined or object-defined error. I copied your entire code and used it. I'm baffled

Comment: F8 through it and tell me where that pops up.

Comment: Here: n = Names("supplierAmount").RefersToRange.Value

Comment: What version of Office are you using?

Comment: If you just change `Names` by `Range` you'll get the value contained in that named range cell.

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion and I'm ashamed that I didnt occur to me. I have changed the code above, let us know how you get on.

Comment: @AndrewWynn Microsoft Excell 2010

Comment: IIRC a `Name` can be a string, number or *range*.  A *Named Range* is just a Name that defines a range.  So to get the "value" of a named range, you have to get the Range from the Name, and then get the Value from the range. So `Names('name').ReferstoRange.Value`.

Comment: You can also do this simpler, safer and faster by using worksheet variables instead of `.Activate` and array copying to and from the cells.